# Fire Sequence.nextval query using jdbctemplate in spring

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

Database : `Oracle`

I have table in which there are 10 columns and i want sequence next value when insert row and also use that sequence number which inserted.

Now i have searched and find that KeyHolder of spring is useful but restrict for only less than 8 field so i can't use that.

How can i fire `"select MySequence.nextval from dual"` query and get sequence using `jdbctemplate(NamedParameterJDBCTemplate)` ?

Is other way to achieve for get inserted sequence value ?.

Answer (score 10):

Using a `jdbctemplate` you can just mention the sequence generator as a value, e.g.

```
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO TABLE (id, data) VALUES (MySequence.nextval, ?)", new Object[] { data });
```

A note regarding the sequence generation: for versions before Oracle 12c you should have a trigger which will increment the sequence for you. From 12c you can use the auto-increment feature.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this by using JdbcTemplate like this :

```
final SqlRowSet sqlRowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(NEXT_VALUE_QUERY);
  sqlRowSet.next();// mandatory to move the cursor 
  sqlRowSet.getLong(1);// the value of the nextval
```